# Can non-commuting matrices share any eigenvectors?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I know commuting matrices share a basis of eigenvectors, and the reverse isn’t true, but can non-commuting matrices ever share even one simultaneous eigenvector?

Answer (score 6):

All upper triangular matrices share an eigenvector (namely, $e_1=(1,0,\ldots,0)^T$), but they do not necessarily commute. E.g. $\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}$ and $\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&1}$ do not commute (and they are both diagonalisable).

Comment: Does this only work because one of the eigenvectors has eigenvalue 0 or can this exist for other cases too?

Comment: @AlexGower The eigenvalue is irrelevant. If $A$ and $B$ share an eigenvector but do not commute, then $A+tI$ and $B$ still share an eigenvector and they don't commute, but you can make $A+tI$ nonsingular with a large $t$.

Comment: Let $e$ be a shared eigenvector of matrices $A$ and $B$.  Then $e$ is both an eigenvector and part of the null space of $AB-BA$.  Commutativity occurs when a complete set of eigenvectors is shared so that the null space of $AB-BA$ is also complete.

Comment: Thanks. How does one prove then that if A and B don’t commute that they cannot share a basis of eigenvectors?

Comment: @AlexGower If they share an eigenbasis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$, with $Av_i=d_iv_i$ and $Bv_i=s_iv_i$, then $ABv_i=d_is_iv_i=BAv_i$ for each $i$. Therefore $A=B$ on the whole vector space. Alternatively, write $A=VDV^{-1}$ and $B=VSV^{-1}$. Then $AB=BA$.

Comment: Aren’t I asking for the proof of the reverse case?

Comment: @AlexGower I proved the contrapositive of your statement. This is commonly known as "proof by contradiction".